# EF 6 Table Per Type Optimistic Concurrency

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, optimistic-concurrency

I have the following table structure:

[image]

And the following model mapping in Entity Framework:

```
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Person>()
        .ToTable("dbo.Person")
        .Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Customer>().ToTable("dbo.Customer");
```

When I update both the `Name` and the `CustomerNumber` this results in two `UPDATE` statements on the database as expected.  But, only one of the records is controlled using optimistic concurrency as shown in the SQL trace below:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Customer]
SET [CustomerNumber] = @0
WHERE ([PersonId] = @1)
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int',@0=N'1234',@1=1

exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Person]
SET [Name] = @0
WHERE (([PersonId] = @1) AND ([RowVersion] = @2))
SELECT [RowVersion]
FROM [dbo].[Person]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [PersonId] = @1',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int,@2 binary(8)',@0=N'Hello',@1=1,@2=0x00000000000007DF
```

There could be a possibility of a race condition on the `Customer` table where this is updated elsewhere WITHOUT updating the timestamp (`RowVersion`) on the `Person` record, resulting in the SQL above overwriting recently persisted changes on the `Customer` record.

Therefore is there a way I can include an additional row version in the EF mappings to control the optimistic concurrency for the `Customer` record to prevent this problem from happening?

From what I understand EF is assuming that the two records for `Person` and `Customer` are being updated in conjunction with each other (where this would capture concurrency issues), where as in reality the records can be updated exclusively from one another.